# How do I put my output csv (list of keys) in a table format where the keys are the top headings and all values are below

Tags: python, networking, cisco, python-tabulate

I am trying to put a list of keys which is a csv output of a python(show ip interface brief) command into a table using some sort of textfsm/tabulate tool. I used tabulate with headers to try and put it in a table but it looks like the ouput(fig.1) in the next section. I expected something with the headers `'intf', 'ipaddr', 'stats', 'proto'`, and each corresponding descriptions to be listed below them. Any help would be a lifesaver!

**fig.1-Output**

intf                                                                                          ipaddr
stats                                                                                         proto

---

```
{'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/21', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'down', 'proto': 'down'}  {'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/22', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'down', 'proto': 'down'}  {'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/23', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'down', 'proto': 'down'}  {'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/24', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'up', 'proto': 'up'}  {'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/25', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'down', 'proto': 'down'}  {'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/26', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'down', 'proto': 'down'}
```

**My code for this looks like this:**

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas 
import csv 
from tabulate import tabulate 
cisco1 = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "host": "cisco",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",

}

command = "show ip interface brief"
with ConnectHandler(**cisco1) as net_connect: 
    output = net_connect.send_command(command, use_textfsm=True)

dataset = [output]
#df = pandas.DataFrame(output)
#df.to_csv('new.csv', index=True, header=True)

headers = ['intf', 'ipaddr', 'stats', 'proto'] 
print(tabulate(dataset, headers = headers))
```

**Expectation:**
I expected something with the headers 'intf', 'ipaddr', 'stats', 'proto', and each corresponding descriptions to be listed below them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The tabular module requires that the input data be a list of lists... but the *output* actually contains a list of dictionaries. So, if I understand you, the question at the end is how to transform a list of dictionaries to a tabulated format...

```
from tabulate import tabulate 

output = [{'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/21', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'down', 'proto': 'down'},
          {'intf': 'GigabitEthernet1/0/22', 'ipaddr': 'unassigned', 'status': 'down', 'proto': 'down'}]
```

You must first transform the list of dictionaries into a list of lists. There are many ways to do this in Python... but this is one.

```
output_list_of_list = [ list(dict.values()) for dict in output]
```

Now you can view in tabular table format...

```
headers = ['intf', 'ipaddr', 'stats', 'proto'] 
tabulated_table = tabulate(output_list_of_list, headers)
print(tabulated_table)
```